# Multiprocessing Function Runs Forever

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have a list of URLs : daily_article_urls. For each URL I want to run the following webscraping code:

```
daily_data=[]
def scrape_article(i,article_url):
    try:
        article_html=requests.get(article_url).content
        article_soup=BeautifulSoup(article_html, 'html.parser')

        article_id=article_soup.select('span[class*="sc-6e54cb25-12 GRQvX"]')
        article_title=article_soup.select_one('div[class="screen-section"] div[class*="sc-"] h2[class*="jvaJJV"]')
        date_published=article_soup.select('span[class*="sc-6e54cb25-12 GRQvX"]')
        appatment_price=article_soup.select_one('aside[class="detail-page-aside"] h1[id="price"]')
        appatment_address=article_soup.select_one('div[class="screen-section"] a[id="address"]')
        apparment_details_1=set([i.get_text(separator='|') if i else None for i in article_soup.select('div[id="details_desc"] div[class*="sc-5fa917ee-0"] div')])
        apparment_details_2=set([i.get_text(separator='|') if i else None for i in article_soup.select('div[id="details_desc"] div[class*="sc-1b705347-0"] div')])

        article_id=article_id[-1].text if article_id else None
        article_title=article_title.text if article_title else None
        date_published=date_published[-2].text if date_published else None
        appatment_price=appatment_price.text if appatment_price else None
        appatment_address=appatment_address.text if appatment_address else None

        aparment_data_dict={'Article ID':article_id,'Article URL':article_url,'Title':article_title,'Date Published':date_published,'Price':appatment_price,'Address':appatment_address,'Details_1':apparment_details_1,'Details_2':apparment_details_2}
        daily_data.append(aparment_data_dict)
        #return aparment_data_dict
    except:
        pass
        #return None
```

webscraping code alone works perfectly, but only few CPU cores are utilized and it takes a lot of time for my 12 CPU core i7 to complete the task. I want to utilize all 12 cores, so I am running the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    daily_article_urls = daily_article_urls# Define your list of article URLs

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12) as pool:
        pool.map(scrape_article, enumerate(daily_article_urls))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The code runs forever. How can I modify the code, so I can utilize all CPU cores?

The same multiprocessing code does not work with this simplier calcualtion function as well:

```
import multiprocessing
import math

def calculate(number):
    try:
        calculated_number = math.sqrt((number**2 + 5*number**3 + 1022))
        return calculated_number
    except Exception as e:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = list(range(10))  # Define your list of article URLs

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12) as pool:
        results = pool.map(calculate, numbers)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Comment: Which particular line in your code requires more processors?

Comment: Do you literally mean "forever" or do you just mean "longer than I'd like"?  Remember, nothing you do can speed up your network connection.  Having more processors doesn't help if you are network-bound.

Comment: The code runs "forever" and does not complete execution after 2-3 minutes, even though there are only 20 urls in the list as an example. 
Let's say there are 30 thousand urls. Can I use multiprocessing, so all CPU cores are utilized instead of only a few?

Comment: The code using multiprocessing is error-free. A straightforward way to investigate the cause of slow execution is to press CTRL+C to trigger a stack trace and diagnose the issue.

Comment: I have tried multiprocessing with more simple function (added above), but still same issue.

Comment: Did you consider debugging your code by, for example, putting a *print("here we go")* line inside *scrape_article()*? If you'd done that you would soon have discovered that the you never saw "here we go" which might have led you to the source of your error. Also, the way you're trying to update the *daily_data* list is fundamentally wrong. Multithreading might be more appropriate in this case for two reasons. 1) It's I/O (network) bound and 2) It makes your list update easier. Furthermore, your last code fragment works without issues but you say it "does not work"

Comment: What environment are you running your code in? OS terminal? IDE? Jupyter Notebook? Google Colab? I tried your mathematical example, and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is broken.  Your code is running forever because all of the threads are dying immediately.

`pool.map(function, args)` calls the function with a single argument.  Your function is expecting two arguments, so it fails immediately.

Try either:

```
def scrape_article(argument):
    i, article_url = argument
```

or else replace `pool.map` with `pool.starmap`

Comment: Unfortunately code execution does still does not stop even after this modification. I have  tried with more simple function (added above)

Comment: Your simplified code works just fine for me.  Are you running it from a Jupyter notebook or something like that?

Comment: i am running on VS Code

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was running it on jupyter notebook inside VS Code. Now i ran the code in .py file and it worked